# Core animation: why can I not composite two animations?

Tags: animation, ios, core-animation

I am trying to animate a wheel

When the finger rests for > 0.1s,  the wheel ' pops out ' ie   I animate  Scale from 1.0 to 1.2.

when the finger moves, the wheel rotates with it ( only if it is popped out ).

But I'm getting a problem: as soon as it starts to rotate, the scale reduces back to 1.0.

```
- (void) spin: (Direction) direction
{
 float thetaOld = thetaWheel;

 float k = (direction == AntiClockwise) ? -1 : 1;
 float t = 2 * M_PI * ( k / 12.0 );
 thetaWheel += t;

 CABasicAnimation * anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

 anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: thetaOld];
 anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: thetaWheel];

 anim.valueFunction = [CAValueFunction functionWithName: kCAValueFunctionRotateZ];

 anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]; 

 anim.duration = 0.1f;
 anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
 anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

 [self.wheelLayer addAnimation: anim forKey:@"transform"];
}

- (void) popOut
{
 CABasicAnimation * anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];

 anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 1.0];
 anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 1.2];

 anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]; 

 anim.duration = 0.25f;
 anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
 anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

 [self.wheelLayer addAnimation: anim forKey:@"transform.scale"];
}

// doesnt get used yet
- (void) popBack
{
 CABasicAnimation * anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];

 anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 1.2];
 anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 1.0];

 anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]; 

 anim.duration = 0.1f;
 anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
 anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

 [self.wheelLayer addAnimation: anim forKey:@"transform.scale"];
}
```

The last routine is not getting used at this time!   So  I can't see what is reducing the scale back to 1...

it looks like somehow the second animation is overwriting the first one...

how to do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess (have not tested that) that layer transform applied in animation for 'transform' keyPath overrides transformation you applied in your scaling animation.

For rotation try using animation with `transform.rotation.z` keypath instead (and you won't need to set valueFunction in that case)

Comment: Works a charm, thank you!  NOTE: transform.rotation.z is needed, transform.rotate.z will fail to register

Comment: @Ohmu, sorry wrote that path from memory and made mistake. I corrected the answer